# Create 1D Texture in DirectX 11

Tags: directx

I try to create the 1D Texture in DirectX 11 wih this code:

## PARAMETER: ID3D11Device* pDevice

```
D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC text1_desc;

::ZeroMemory(&text1_desc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE1D_DESC));

text1_desc.Width = 258

text1_desc.MipLevels = 2;

text1_desc.ArraySize = 2;

text1_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;

text1_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

text1_desc.Format = R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

FLOAT* pData = new FLOAT[text1_desc.MipLevels * text1_desc.ArraySize * text1_desc.Width];

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA sr_data;

::ZeroMemory(&sr_data, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));

sr_data.pSysMem = pData;

ID3D11Texture1D* pTexture1D = nullptr;

auto hr = pDevice->CreateTexture1D(&text1_desc, &sr_data, &pTexture1D);
```

When `text1_desc.MipLevels = 1` and `text1_desc.ArraySize = 1` everything is good.

When `text1_desc.MipLevels = 0` or `text1_desc.MipLevels > 1` it raises Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEE6D14CC0 (nvwgf2umx.dll): 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Ryan Wheale, Thank you very much for the information, I'm grateful. You helped me a lot. Thomas Papamihos.

Answer (score 2):

Mip-levels of '0' is a problem since it results in an allocation size of '0'. You need to figure out the number of mip-levels that will get generated for the given input width. So for 0, you need something like:

```
size_t mipLevels = 1;
size_t width = 258;
while ( width > 1 )
{
    if ( width > 1 )
        width >>= 1;
    ++mipLevels;
}
```

The second thing to note is that you have to pass an array of `D3D11_SUBRESOURE_DATA` instances, not just one, if you are creating a complex resource. There is one `D3D11_SUBRESOURE_DATA` per sub-resource, which needs to be `mipLevels * text1_desc.ArraySize` in length. You only ever allocate 1, which is why you get a runtime fault.

You should look at [DirectXTex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248926) for code that works with a all kinds of Direct3D 11 textures.

Comment: Chuck Walbourn, Thank you very much for the information, I'm grateful. You helped me a lot. Thomas Papamihos.